# passing FlatList item to multiple navigation in React Narive Drawer and Tab

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-native-flatlist, react-navigation-bottom-tab, react-navigation-v6

When i use React Native navigation ( Drawer Navigation )
i can pass simply FlatList item
My FlatList render view

```
const SingleChamber = ({item,navigation}) => {
  
  const { t, i18n } = useTranslation();
  return (
    <View style={{padding:10,borderWidth:2,marginHorizontal:5, marginVertical:10,borderRadius:20, backgroundColor:'#861010',borderColor:'#fffbbb'}} >
       <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation.navigate('C_Home',{name:item.name,id:item.id})}>
        <View style={{flex:1,flexDirection:'row',alignItems:'center'}}>
          <Image source={{uri: item.image}} style={{width:90,height:70,borderRadius:2,marginHorizontal:5, resizeMode:"stretch"}} />
          {i18n.language==='en' && <Text style={{fontSize:16,fontWeight:'bold',paddingLeft:5}}>{item.name}</Text>}
          {i18n.language==='ar' && <Text style={{fontSize:16,fontWeight:'bold',paddingLeft:5}}>{item.name_translate}</Text>}

        </View>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      
    </View>
  )
}
```

and i received item name in screen by using the following

```
const ChamberHome = ({navigation,route}) => {
    
  return (
    <View>
      <Text>Chamber Details</Text>
      <Text>{route.params.name}</Text>
      
     
    </View>
  )
}
```

And my  Drawer Navigation file is the following

```
<Drawer.Screen name="C_Home" component={ChamberHome} />
```

**But when i try to migrate a Tab Navigation with Drawer Navigation as the following**
In Drawer navigation file

```
<Drawer.Screen name="C_Home" component={TabNavigator} />
```

my Tab Navigation File

```
<Tab.Navigator>
    <Tab.Screen name='C_Home' component={ChamberHome}  options={{
        title:t('chamber_Home')}}  />
    <Tab.Screen name='Chamber_Division' component={ChamberDivision}/>

    

  </Tab.Navigator>
```

I received the following error message ***cannot read property'name' of undefined***
[image]

***note: if i removed route.params.name , i can navigate correctly***

```
 const ChamberHome = ({navigation,route}) => {
    
  return (
    <View>
      <Text>Chamber Details</Text>
      {/* <Text>{route.params.name}</Text> */}
      
     
    </View>
  )
}
```